# SCSS: Mixins may only be defined at the root of a document

Tags: firefox, sass

I've been using SASS for a couple of days now and encountered a certain problem.

Here's the SCSS that renders perfectly:

```
@import "light";
@import "basic";
@import "fancybox";
```

Since it's a user style, Firefox requires all site specific CSS in @-moz-document rule, like this:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
@-moz-document domain("clubfile.ru"){
    @import "light";
    @import "basic";
    @import "fancybox";
}
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work and compiler returns an error:

> Mixins may only be defined at the root of a document

and a reference to mixins in _basic.scss. Gem versions are Sass 3.1.20 and Compass 0.12.2.

So, is there a way to fix or ignore that error?

**Update 1:** I think -moz rule syntax, similar to SCSS mixins, is causing all the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your "light", "basic" or "fancybox" files contain mixin definitions, or import files that contain mixin definitions? If so, you're going to have to move the mixins out.

You could try moving your mixins into a _mixins partial and @import that only where needed.

Comment: "basic" contains all the definitions. I've tried two ways of moving them:
1.Create _mixins and import it before other import in the root scss file. Then I'm getting "undefined mixins error".
2.Define mixins as is in the root scss before import. Works great, but it's against DRY to have same stuff in numerous files.

Comment: Are "light", "basic" and "fancybox" partials? If not, they probably should be. It's bad practice to import directly-compiling Sass files. If you convert them to partials, they will stop complaining about undefined mixins, because they won't be compiled until a file imports them (and you will have imported _mixins up above).

Comment: Managed to compile it with separate mixins @import at beginning of root. Thanks for help.